# Options for Persisting Data in iPhone Development

Tags: iphone, ios

What are my different options of persisting data entered in an iPhone application?

NSUserDefaults: Small amount of data

Web Service: iOS code triggers web service and saves the data into the database

Can I save the data into some database which is present locally on the iPhone? If yes how does the user backup the saved data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQLite directly or via [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html). You just keep the db file in Documents directory of your app's filesystem sandbox and iTunes/iCloud will back it up automagically.

In iOS 5, you can even store Core Data changes to iCloud automatically on every change and sync it between apps.

Comment: However if you delete/uninstall an app is that user entered data saved locally? I believe it is but how do you call that saved data back into a re-installed version of the app?

Comment: No, documents directory of each app is deleted along with the app when you uninstall it. If you synced it to iCloud, you can get it back after reinstall, but that's for a new question.